# SCIPgetSolVal from SCIP solver is not returning the solution values

Tags: c++, scip

I have been using SCIP for some time and have never had problems with these functions. However, I recently ran several input scenarios to pull different results from scip.
There was a case where the SCIPgetSolVal function did not work as it should.

If I do SCIPprintBestSol (scipProblem, NULL, TRUE) it shows me the results and they are within limits. When I next get the results with the SCIPgetSolVal function it returns me values of magnitude "1E + 99".

Note that it always works, except for some cases, I think the most logical thing is to be a problem with the input data, but I think in that case SCIPprintBestSol would not have viable results.

It seems to me like a memory allocation problem but I don't understand why it happens and how I can fix it.

I don't know if it's relevant but it's in c ++ on windows.

```
    SCIPsolve(scipProblem);
    SCIPprintBestSol(scipProblem, NULL, TRUE); //VALID RESULTS

    /* SCIP Problem Results */
    SCIP_Status status = SCIPgetStatus(scipProblem);

    if(status == SCIP_STATUS_INFEASIBLE)
    {
      result = false;
    }
    else
    {
      for(int t=0; t<100; t++)
      {
         result(t,0) = SCIPgetSolVal(scipProblem, sol, probVars.at(t));
         cout<< "Solution :"<<  result(t,0) << endl;//WRONG RESULTS
      }
    }
```

Comment: Just to make sure it is not a very simple problem: Your instances have at least 100 variables? How do you set `sol` and `probVars`?

Comment: I apologize for not having added more code, but it is a very large problem and has many other variables, and would make this very extensive. In the other variables it getthe values well.

This particular variable is giving problems. Yes it's exactly 100. The sol I get from getBestSol, but honestly it gives me the same result if I just replace sol with NULL.

Comment: So you are calling getBestSol after you print the best solution at the top of your snippet? What do you get if you call SCIPprintSol(scipProblem, sol, NULL, TRUE)? What is the status? I see that it is not infeasible, but there are some other possible status codes where SCIP did not necessarily find a solution.

Comment: To expand on @Gerald, the line seems missing in the snippet: `SCIP_SOL* sol = SCIPgetBestSol (scip);`